# what does it mean 'push @{bla bla }' in Perl?

Tags: perl

I read try to read perl code of annovar and there is a line like this:

```
push @{$genedb{$chr, $nextbin}}, [$name, $dbstrand, $txstart, $txend, $cdsstart, $cdsend, [@exonstart], [@exonend], $name2];
```

Can someone explain what does it mean?
which values put which array or hash ?

Comment: Start with `perldoc -f push`. The rest is so context dependent that it's impossible to answer here.

Comment: Two key things:

Comment: 1) If `@NAME` returns an array, so does `@BLOCK`. The former references the array by name, while the latter uses a reference.

Comment: 2) Dereferencing a reference in lvalue context will autovivify it, so `push @{ $genedb{$chr, $nextbin} }, ...` means `push @{ $genedb{$chr, $nextbin} //= [] }, ...`.

Comment: I understand now. I confused because it create key and push array to key value, but key value not defined as array  before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run this program and Data::Dumper will show the results

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use feature qw<say>;

use Data::Dumper;

my %genedb;
my $chr = 'G';
my $nextbin = 4143;

push @{$genedb{$chr, $nextbin}}, [1..10];

print Dumper(\%genedb);

exit(0);
```